# reduce number of for loop

Tags: c++, opencv

I wrote a code to detect pedestrians. the code is completely working but as you see in below code there are many for loops. my question is how i can reduce the numbers of for loops without effects on the output.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp> 
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp> 
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp> 
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame );

/** Global variables */
CascadeClassifier pedestrians_cascade;
Mat image1,image2,image3,image4,image5,image6,image7,image8,image9,image10;
Mat ped1,ped2,ped3,ped4,ped5,ped6,ped7,ped8,ped9,ped10;
int x;
int y;
int width, height;

int main( )
{
    // Load Face cascade (.xml file)
    pedestrians_cascade = CascadeClassifier("hogcascade_pedestrians.xml");

    // Read an images
    image1 = imread("ped1.jpg");
    image2 = imread("ped2.jpg");
    image3 = imread("ped3.jpg");
    image4 = imread("ped4.jpg");
    image5 = imread("ped5.jpg");
    image6 = imread("ped6.jpg");
    image7 = imread("ped7.jpg");
    image8 = imread("ped8.jpg");
    image9 = imread("ped9.jpg");
    image10 = imread("ped10.jpg");

     // these functions use to draw rectangles
    std::vector<Rect> ped1;
    pedestrians_cascade.detectMultiScale( image1, ped1, 1.1, , 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
    for (int i = 0; i < ped1.size(); i++) // Iterate through all current elements (detected ped)
    {
       Point pt1(ped1[i].x, ped1[i].y); // Display detected ped on main window - live stream from camera
       Point pt2((ped1[i].x + ped1[i].width), (ped1[i].y + ped1[i].height));
        //rectangle(image1, ped1[i], Scalar(255, 0 , 0), 2, 8, 0);
        rectangle(image1,pt2,pt1, Scalar(255,0,0), 2,8,0);
    }

    std::vector<Rect> ped2;
    pedestrians_cascade.detectMultiScale( image2, ped2, 1.1, 5, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
    for (int i = 0; i < ped2.size(); i++) // Iterate through all current elements (detected ped)
    {
        Point pt1(ped2[i].x, ped2[i].y); // Display detected ped on main window - live stream from camera
        Point pt2((ped2[i].x + ped2[i].width), (ped2[i].y + ped2[i].height));
        rectangle(image2, pt2, pt1, Scalar(255, 0 , 0), 2, 8, 0);
    }

    std::vector<Rect> ped3;
    pedestrians_cascade.detectMultiScale( image3, ped3, 1.1, 2, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
    for (int i = 0; i < ped3.size(); i++) // Iterate through all current elements (detected ped)
    {
        Point pt1(ped3[i].x, ped3[i].y); // Display detected ped on main window - live stream from camera
        Point pt2((ped3[i].x + ped3[i].width), (ped3[i].y + ped3[i].height));
        rectangle(image3, pt2, pt1, Scalar(255, 0 , 0), 2, 8, 0);
    }

    std::vector<Rect> ped4;
    pedestrians_cascade.detectMultiScale( image4, ped4, 1.1, 2, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
    for (int i = 0; i < ped4.size(); i++) // Iterate through all current elements (detected ped)
    {
        Point pt1(ped4[i].x, ped4[i].y); // Display detected ped on main window - live stream from camera
        Point pt2((ped4[i].x + ped4[i].width), (ped4[i].y + ped4[i].height));
        rectangle(image4, pt2, pt1, Scalar(255, 0 , 0), 2, 8, 0);
    }

    std::vector<Rect> ped5;
    pedestrians_cascade.detectMultiScale( image5, ped5, 1.1, 2, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
    for (int i = 0; i < ped5.size(); i++) // Iterate through all current elements (detected ped)
    {
        Point pt1(ped5[i].x, ped5[i].y); // Display detected ped on main window - live stream from camera
        Point pt2((ped5[i].x + ped5[i].width), (ped5[i].y + ped5[i].height));
        rectangle(image5, pt2, pt1, Scalar(255, 0 , 0), 2, 8, 0);
    }

    std::vector<Rect> ped6;
    pedestrians_cascade.detectMultiScale( image6, ped6, 1.1, 2, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
    for (int i = 0; i < ped6.size(); i++) // Iterate through all current elements (detected ped)
    {
        Point pt1(ped6[i].x, ped6[i].y); // Display detected ped on main window - live stream from camera
        Point pt2((ped6[i].x + ped6[i].width), (ped6[i].y + ped6[i].height));
        rectangle(image6, pt2, pt1, Scalar(255, 0 , 0), 2, 8, 0);
    }

    std::vector<Rect> ped7;
    pedestrians_cascade.detectMultiScale( image7, ped7, 1.1, 2, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
    for (int i = 0; i < ped7.size(); i++) // Iterate through all current elements (detected ped)
    {
        Point pt1(ped7[i].x, ped7[i].y); // Display detected ped on main window - live stream from camera
        Point pt2((ped7[i].x + ped7[i].width), (ped7[i].y + ped7[i].height));
        rectangle(image7, pt2, pt1, Scalar(255, 0 , 0), 2, 8, 0);
    }

    std::vector<Rect> ped8;
    pedestrians_cascade.detectMultiScale( image8, ped8, 1.1, 20, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
    for (int i = 0; i < ped8.size(); i++) // Iterate through all current elements (detected ped)
    {
        Point pt1(ped8[i].x, ped8[i].y); // Display detected ped on main window - live stream from camera
        Point pt2((ped8[i].x + ped8[i].width), (ped8[i].y + ped8[i].height));
        rectangle(image8, pt2, pt1, Scalar(255, 0 , 0), 2, 8, 0);
    }

    std::vector<Rect> ped9;
    pedestrians_cascade.detectMultiScale( image9, ped9, 1.1, 2, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
    for (int i = 0; i < ped9.size(); i++) // Iterate through all current elements (detected ped)
    {
        Point pt1(ped9[i].x, ped9[i].y); // Display detected ped on main window - live stream from camera
        Point pt2((ped9[i].x + ped9[i].width), (ped9[i].y + ped9[i].height));
        rectangle(image9, pt2, pt1, Scalar(255, 0 , 0), 2, 8, 0);
    }

    std::vector<Rect> ped10;
    pedestrians_cascade.detectMultiScale( image10, ped10, 1.1, 2, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
    for (int i = 0; i < ped10.size(); i++) // Iterate through all current elements (detected ped)
    {
        Point pt1(ped10[i].x, ped10[i].y); // Display detected ped on main window - live stream from camera
        Point pt2((ped10[i].x + ped10[i].width), (ped10[i].y + ped10[i].height));
        rectangle(image10, pt2, pt1, Scalar(255, 0 , 0), 2, 8, 0);
    }

    imshow( "ped1", image1);
    /*imshow( "ped2", image2);
    imshow( "ped3", image3);
    imshow( "ped4", image4);
    imshow( "ped5", image5);
    imshow( "ped6", image6);
    imshow( "ped7", image7);
    imshow( "ped8", image8);
    imshow( "ped9", image9);
    imshow( "ped10", image10);*/
    waitKey(0);                   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question is probably more suited to [codereview.se](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Why do you want to reduce the number of four loops? I would rather recommend you to add at least one, because to me it seems like you wrote almost exact code 10 times just to do 10 times the same thing with different objects

Comment: the code is too long and I repeated the for loops for 10 times. I would like to minimize the for loops, but I don't know how I can do't without effects on the output

Comment: @AdelKhatem , this is a codereview question :/

Comment: NASA, we've got problems here.  You have `ped1` declared globally as a `Mat` type.  You also create a shadow variable, `ped1` as a `std::vector` inside `main`.  Which variable are you referring to? This is with the other `ped` variables as well.

Comment: Looks like you need to place the images and the `ped` into a container or containers.  This will allow you to have one outer loop.

Comment: As punishment for producing this sort of.. um.. code, you shall write 1000x (by hand) "I shall not repeat myself." :P | But seriously, if you have to copy/paste the same code (let alone 10 times), it's a good sign that you should probably turn it into a function.

Comment: I do not think so that the for loops can be reduced. Yes! the code is repetitive and can definitely benefit from a function or nested for loops as suggested by Thomas. However, it does not reduce the overall number of loops or in other words the Big-O notation. This is not possible, atleast with the information provided.

Comment: @masad Somehow I don't think the question was about algorithmic complexity.

Comment: @DanMašek hmmm, its a bit ambiguous. If complexity is not to be reduced then i think this question is answered below. Complexity is the first thing I think when someone tells me to reduce the number of loops.

Answer (score 0):

Make an outer `std::vector` for images and `ped` variables:

```
std::vector<Mat> images(10);
std::vector<vector<Rect> > peds;
// ...
for (unsigned int p = 0; p < 10; ++p)
{
    pedestrians_cascade.detectMultiScale( images[p], peds[p],
                                         1.1, 5,
                                         0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE,
                                         Size(30, 30) );
    for (int i = 0; i < peds[p].size(); i++) // Iterate through all current elements (detected ped)
    {
        Point pt1(peds[p][i].x, peds[p][i].y); // Display detected ped on main window - live stream from camera
        Point pt2((peds[p][i].x + peds[p][i].width),
                  (peds[p][i].y + peds[p][i].height));
        rectangle(images[p],
                  pt2, pt1,
                  Scalar(255, 0 , 0), 2, 8, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually he might need a little more (perhaps a vector of structs containing image + params), since at least one of the parameters (`neighborcount`) differ in some of the invocations. Hard to tell (but hardly surprising it got missed with such copy/paste mess) if that's a mistake or intent.

Comment: I used this code but I got error. the error is (no match in ++ped)

Comment: @AdelKhatem There was a pretty obvious typo (`++ped` instead of `++p`). You need to think and reason about the code a little rather than just blindly copy it.